# Finding the analytic function of $z$, given the real part

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-riemann-equations

> **Problem.** The real part of an analytic function $f(z)$ is given by $3x^2y-y^3$. Find the imaginary part. Find the analytic function of
> $z$.

---

**Attempt.** I begin by applying the Cauchy-Riemann Equations. As $f(z)$ is given to be analytic, we may conclude that:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

Where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are the *real* and *imaginary* parts of $f(z)$, respectively ($x,y\in\mathbb{R}$). Hence,

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 6xy \;\;\;\;\;\;\; -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 3x^2-3y^2$$

Integrating these, we obtain:

$$f(z) = \int 6xy\;dy = 3xy^2 + C(x)\;\;\;\;\;\; f(z) = \int -(3x^2-3y^2)\;dx = 3xy^2-x^3 + C(y)$$

Then, the imaginary part of $f(z)$ is given by the sum of the two integrals, $6xy^2 - x^3$, hence:

$$f(z) = 3x^2y-y^3 + i(6xy^2-x^3)$$.

---

Unfortunately, I seem to have erred somewhere. **Where have I gone wrong? Is this a valid approach?**

Comment: Why are you adding the two $f(z)$s?

Comment: @sku Oops! Thanks for pointing that out, not sure what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

$u(x,y) = 3x^2y-y^3
$

$u_x = v_y =6xy 
$

$ u_y=-v_x = 3x^2-3y^2$

$  dv = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}dy$

$  dv = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx +\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy$
$v = (-3x^2+3y^2)dx +6xydy$

this is an exact differential  equation( check it)
so $v = \int_{y=constant}3y^2-3x^2dx + \int_{x=0}6xydy$ \

$v=3y^2x-x^3 +c_1
$

$f(x,y)= u(x,y)+v(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3 +i(3xy^2-x^3-c_1)
$

Comment: there are also other methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is $v(x,y)=3xy^2+C(x)$. We know that $v_x(x,y)=3y^2-3x^2$ so $C'(x)==-3x^2$ Hence $C(x)=-x^3+A$ where A is a complex constant. Now$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$